# Converting 180° of motion to 270° of motion via gear ratio

Tags: geometry

I am very new to math / physics not sure if this is the best network to ask or if math is better but I am working on a project where I only need 270° of motion to turn a potentiometer from a servo that can turn 180°. If I did a gear ratio of 2:1 I could get 360° of motion, but that is more than I need. How would I figure out the ratio needed? It would be less than a 2:1.

Comment: This is a question about mathematics, not physics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you could try [reducing fractions](https://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/math/fractionssimplify.php).  In this case, I’d say 3:2.